# C# - How do I get an anonymous type and then use the same selector to create an object?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, azure-cosmosdb

So I'm trying out Azure's new DocumentDB. Unfortunately it doesn't allow selectors to a type. It won't let me do:

```
public IEnumerable<U> GetAll<U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> selector)
{
    return Client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(Collection.DocumentsLink)
        .Select(selector)
        .AsEnumerable();
}
```

and use it as:

```
// Doesn't work
return GetAll(t => new MyViewModel {
    Id = t.Id,
    Name = t.Name,
    Email = t.Email,
    Url = t.Url
});
```

It says it only supports anonymous types. (I imagine since it's fairly new that will change at some point).

I can solve the problem using a second select:

```
return GetAll(t => new {
    Id = t.Id,
    Name = t.Name,
    Email = t.Email,
    Url = t.Url
}).Select(t => new MyViewModel() {
    Id = t.Id,
    Name = t.Name,
    Email = t.Email,
    Url = t.Url
}).AsEnumerable();
```

However that is a pain.

Is there a way to use the same selector twice and just make it anonymous the first time?

Comment: In your "Dpesn't Work" section above, what happens if you change your first line to `return GetAll(t => new { // So basically omit MyViewModel`

Comment: It works, but doesn't come back as the type I want. It comes back as an an anonymous type with 4 strings. So I have to do the second select to get it to the type I want so I can pass my ViewModel to the view. I'm trying to avoid the second select.

Comment: I meant, you could use [automapper](http://automapper.org/)... From the site: *AutoMapper is a simple little library built to solve a deceptively complex problem - getting rid of code that mapped one object to another.*

Answer (score 1):

You'll notice the signature for `GetAll` contains `Expression<Func<T, U>> selector`. The `Expression` part says that this argument is being passed as an expression tree and not as a `Func` delegate. It's done this way so that the provider can parse the selector and generate the appropriate database calls (often SQL) to fetch your data.

Now, when you use a specific custom type - in your case `MyViewModel` - the provider hits a problem - it just doesn't know how to convert that type into the database calls. It does know how to translate an anonymous type though.

In then returns an `IEnumerable<U>` so data returned by `GetAll` is now in memory so you can then perform the subsequent creation of the `MyViewModel` type. There's no need to translate to database calls any more.

So the answer is that this is by design. It is very unlikely that this will be a new feature in the future.